# Build error in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: gradle, android-support-library

I am getting the following error in android studio 3.1.3 when i try to rebuild my firebase login app.please help

```
support-compat-27.1.1.aar\76a2bb1ead9b3a164321ee3d23767645\res\values
\values.xml:50:4: Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed 
character data or markup.
```

Comment: If you could provide us the contents of your file, we could help you but it looks like there is some sort of syntax error in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the file values.xml inside the values folder. I'm sure there is a character like an exclamation mark ! or a double quote put in between other double quotes "

Provide more info on what is inside the values.xml file to get more accurate answer.